# Selenium Webdriver using C#: How to find a URL from number of URL on a webpage and click on it?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a C# script in selenium websdriver to test a website and got stuck in between. I have a multiple URL's on a webpage and I need to find one URL out of them and apply a click event on it. The URL names are dynamic hence its difficult for me to find it using 'ID' or 'name'. The URL name can be anything for example: the_rise_of_India.htm or the_rise_india.htm or the_riseIndia.htm etc... How can I filter and find my desired URL and click on it?

Kindly help me on the above scenario.

My HTML code is:

```
<table xmlns:downloader="http://schemas.niku.com/java/com.niku.dms.web.ZipPageDownloader" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" class="tableGridList" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr class="TableGridList"><td class="ColHeadNoSort" scope="col"><a href="javascript:checkAllOver('dms.fileManager');"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/IcoCheckAll.gif" border="0" alt="Check All" title="Check All"></a></td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" colspan="3" align="center" scope="col">Name</td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" align="center" scope="col">&nbsp;</td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" scope="col">Size</td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" scope="col">Type</td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" scope="col">Status</td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" scope="col">Modified</td><td class="ColHeadNoSort" scope="col">Actions</td></tr>
                <tr valign="top" class="rowOff" onmouseover="this.className='rowOn'" onmouseout="this.className='rowOff'"><td valign="middle" align="center" width="20" scope="row">&nbsp;</td><td valign="middle" width="20" class="hierTee"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/Spacer.gif" height="16" width="16" border="0" alt=""></td><td valign="middle"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/fmFolderClosed.gif" alt="" title=""></td><td valign="middle" width="100%"><a class="tableLink" target="" href="app?action=dms.ProjectsfileManager&amp;folderId=5697033&amp;returnAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;cancelAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;actionItemId=&amp;id=5103184&amp;type=Projects&amp;taskID=&amp;fromPage=&amp;rootFolderId=&amp;">Great India's place</a></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true" id="PPP"></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="center" nowrap="true">9/26/15 8:27 PM</td><td valign="middle" align="right"><select name="folder5697033" onchange="optionGoTo( this.form.name,'folder5697033')" class="docMgrAction"><option value=""></option></select></td></tr>
                <tr valign="top" class="rowOff" onmouseover="this.className='rowOn'" onmouseout="this.className='rowOff'"><td valign="middle" align="center" width="20" scope="row">&nbsp;</td><td valign="middle" width="20" class="hierTee"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/Spacer.gif" height="16" width="16" border="0" alt=""></td><td valign="middle"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/fmFolderClosed.gif" alt="" title=""></td><td valign="middle" width="100%"><a class="tableLink" target="" href="app?action=dms.ProjectsfileManager&amp;folderId=5687045&amp;returnAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;cancelAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;actionItemId=&amp;id=5103184&amp;type=Projects&amp;taskID=&amp;fromPage=&amp;rootFolderId=&amp;">India's silver gold awards</a></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true" id="PPP"></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="center" nowrap="true">8/6/15 12:04 PM</td><td valign="middle" align="right"><select name="folder5687045" onchange="optionGoTo( this.form.name,'folder5687045')" class="docMgrAction"><option value=""></option></select></td></tr>
                <tr valign="top" class="rowOff" onmouseover="this.className='rowOn'" onmouseout="this.className='rowOff'"><td valign="middle" align="center" width="20" scope="row">&nbsp;</td><td valign="middle" width="20" class="hierTee"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/Spacer.gif" height="16" width="16" border="0" alt=""></td><td valign="middle"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/fmFolderClosed.gif" alt="" title=""></td><td valign="middle" width="100%"><a class="tableLink" target="" href="app?action=dms.ProjectsfileManager&amp;folderId=5693965&amp;returnAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;cancelAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;actionItemId=&amp;id=5103184&amp;type=Projects&amp;taskID=&amp;fromPage=&amp;rootFolderId=&amp;">India's Gold awards</a></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true" id="PPP"></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="center" nowrap="true">9/8/15 10:02 AM</td><td valign="middle" align="right"><select name="folder5693965" onchange="optionGoTo( this.form.name,'folder5693965')" class="docMgrAction"><option value=""></option></select></td></tr>
                <tr valign="top" class="rowOff" onmouseover="this.className='rowOn'" onmouseout="this.className='rowOff'"><td valign="middle" align="center" width="20" scope="row">&nbsp;</td><td valign="middle" width="20" class="hierTee"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/Spacer.gif" height="16" width="16" border="0" alt=""></td><td valign="middle"><img src="ui/evolution1/images/fmFolderClosed.gif" alt="" title=""></td><td valign="middle" width="100%"><a class="tableLink" target="" href="app?action=dms.ProjectsfileManager&amp;folderId=5691948&amp;returnAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;cancelAction=dms.ProjectsFileManager&amp;actionItemId=&amp;id=5103184&amp;type=Projects&amp;taskID=&amp;fromPage=&amp;rootFolderId=&amp;">Awards night - India</a></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true" id="PPP"></td><td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="right" nowrap="true"></td><td valign="middle" align="center" nowrap="true">8/28/15 7:30 AM</td><td valign="middle" align="right"><select name="folder5691948" onchange="optionGoTo( this.form.name,'folder5691948')" class="docMgrAction"><option value=""></option></select></td></tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

The URL names are dynamic and I need to search the string and click on it.

Answer (score 1):

SO if I understand your question properly , You just need to get the list of all the displayed URLS and click on your desired one.

1 st easy way.

```
Webelement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='the_right_url.htm']"));
```

you can put a check here if you want to verify the URL is displayed on the page
by

```
if(element!=null)
    element.click()
else
    //test fails
```

the 2nd way you can get the list of URLS which are displayed on the page and then click on the desired one by index number

`Webelements [] ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath(//*/li))` //let say the URLs are coming under li tags

now you can navigate through the list `ele` using loop may be for loop and get the index number`(using come count let say count)` where your desired url is displaying.

and then click on it using

```
driver.findelemenet(By.xpath(//*/li[count]));
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun, but the main problem is the URL's contains only string and I need to search the string among all the URL's and find my desired URL and then perform click event.
For example: Lets take hypothetical example, I have few URL's with different names and I know only 'part' of the string. SO what I need to do is, first I need to match my string with URL's and find my URL and click on it.

Comment: Then you can just try with Webelement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'the_partial_string')]"));

Comment: Thanks, I tried with above examples, but it does not work. In my scenario, following are the URL coming dynamically on a web page:

 - Great India's place
 - India's silver gold awards
 - India's Gold awards
 - Awards night India

And I want to click on "India's Gold awards" URL, for that I stored a partial string 'Gold awards' in a variable name 'urlname'.

Now I am using the below syntax to click on "India's Gold awards" URL:

driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(urlname)).Click(); 

Bt it does not work.

Comment: @AshishSharma Regarding PartialLinkText, as for as I found the details by googling PartialLinkText should have the starting substring as in ur case it should have "India's Gold" or something like that(Maybe I am wrong), Why are you not trying with driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("India's Gold")).Click();

Answer (score 0):

If you have text that you know will always appear in the link you can find it by partial text

```
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("india"));
```

Or using contains

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//[contains(text(), 'india')]"));
```

Please note both options are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with above examples, but it does not work. In my scenario, following are the URL coming dynamically on a web page:

 - Great India's place
 - India's silver gold awards
 - India's Gold awards
 - Awards night India

And I want to click on "India's Gold awards" URL, for that I stored a partial string 'Gold awards' in a variable name 'urlname'.

Now I am using the below syntax to click on "India's Gold awards" URL:

driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(urlname)).Click(); 

Bt it does not work.

Comment: @AshishSharma the url is text or assign to attribute? like `name="url"` or `href="url"`

Comment: URL is nothing its just a text to explain my comment. The syntax is: driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(urlname)).Click();

Comment: @AshishSharma I asked about the html structure, not the code.

Comment: @AshishSharma Can you post an example of such url?

Comment: here is my code: 'string urlname = "Gold awards";  driver.FindElement(By.Id("projmgr.projectDefaultTab")).Click(); 
driver.FindElement(By.Id("dms.ProjectsFileManager")).Click(); 
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(urlname)).Click(); '

Comment: @AshishSharma Click on "edit" under your post and add it to your question

Comment: @AshishSharma The text is "India's Gold awards". If you want to use `.LinkText` you need to give the full text `By.LinkText("India's Gold awards")`. To use "Gold awards" you need to use `PartialLinkText` `By.PartialLinkText("Gold awards")`

Comment: When I am using "By.PartialLinkText("Gold awards")" it does not work for me. What could be the reason. I am using the following code: driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(urlname)).Click();